# Eloquent relation with condition where it self

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have problem with calling relation with condition it self

this is my scheme

```
table bank
|id|cash_id|type

table cash_small
|id|title|

table cash_big
|id|title|
```

I need call dynamic condition for relationship based on **type** of table bank

```
public function small(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\CashSmall', 'cash_id')->where('type','small');
}

public function big(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\CashSmall', 'cash_id')->where('type','big');
}
```

but the result is, where condition is working on relation table, **not in bank table**

Could you help me to fix this problem?

Thannk's

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to use a Polymorphic relationship.

Comment: the table bank can have more than one `cash_small` or `cash_big`? I mean bank has one to many relationship with cash_small or cash_big?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay yes cash_id can be used for cash_small or cash_big based on type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you have 2 different table for `small_cash`,`big_cash`. Have a single table called `cash` and have a field called `type`. Then you can use laravel local scope.

So in your model `Bank.php` you will have a relationship called cash.

```
public function cash() 
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Cash', 'cash_id');
}
```

Now in `Cash.php` you can create a scope like so

```
public function scopeSize($query, $type = 'small') //can be whatever you want
{
    return $query->where('type', $type);
}
```

Now all you do is add query scope when you need like so `$bank->cash()->size('small');`

Now your `cash()` method will return all the cash and add scope to filter the result you want.

More more info have a look at laravel scope documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent